Azure DevOps AWS CLI with Powershell
I have a AWSShellScript task that executed a powershell script - example below trimmed for this post.
-task: AWSShellScript@1
  inputs:
    scriptType: inline
    inlineScript: 'pwsh -File test-script.ps1 -pathValue $(pathValue)'

The script above passes the value "pathvalue" to the script and everything works as expected.
The problem I have is that the value is actually "/pathvalue" and I unfortunately cannot remove the leading "/" from the string as its part of a legacy systems that can't currently be changed.
When passing this value, the string value itself is changed by the task presumably and instead of receiving "/pathvalue", the script recieves "c:/program files/git/pathvalue".
Does anybody know how to stop parameters appended with "/" from being treated as a relative path and appending the folder?
The pipeline variable is defined as follows:
- name: pathValue
  value: '/apigw/sub'

The powershell script uses the value as follows:
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$pathValue
)
Write-Host " > Path: $pathValue"


Try adding a period : -path .'pathvalue;

Hi @user1474992, have you checked my update below? Did it work you?

I can reproduce the issue when using -path ''/pathvalue''.

To resolve it, you can add a / to escape the / in your path.
- task: AWSShellScript@1
  inputs:
    scriptType: 'inline'
    inlineScript: 'pwsh -File test-script.ps1 -path ''//pathvalue'''


Result:


Update
Workaround1: Using vmImage: ubuntu-latest.
Testing in my pipeline, using ubuntu-latest works as expected when the value of your variable is /apigw/sub.

Workaround2: If you must use windows-latest, set the value of your variable to apigw/sub then add / in your test-script.ps1 if needed.
variables:
- name: pathValue
  value: 'apigw/sub'

For example,
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$pathValue
)

$newpath = "/" + $pathValue
Write-Host " > Path: $pathValue "
Write-Host " > NewPath: $newpath "

Result:


This unfortunately didn't work for me - presumably because I use a variable as follows:

Can you share how you use the variable in your test-script.ps1?

Liu I have updated my description to show how the variable is declared and then used in the powershell script

Hi @user1474992, I have shared two workarounds, see the update above.
